# merge two folders and keeping the files have same name

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I have multiple sources folder(these folders have a lot of files named such as ip address `Ex: 192.168.2.1` ), I want to merge them in a target folder.

What is the ways of doing this operation on a Linux using terminal.

**Source 1**

```
/Desktop/source1/192.168.2.1
/Desktop/source1/192.168.2.2
/Desktop/source1/192.168.2.3
```

**Source 2**

```
/Desktop/source2/192.168.2.1
/Desktop/source2/192.168.2.2
/Desktop/source2/192.168.2.3
```

**Source 3**

```
/Desktop/source2/192.168.2.1
```

**Source 4**

**Source 5**

**Source 6**

.

.

.

**Target**

```
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.1
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.2
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.3
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.1.copy
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.2.copy
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.3.copy
/Desktop/target/192.168.2.1.copy.copy
```

original files have no file extension I just named them as what they are but I am opening them in gedit or any text editor. The duplicated file suffix might be ('192.168.2.3.copy or 192.168.2.3_2 or anything just needs to be different)

What is the way of doing this operation with cp command, shell script or any other command in Linux?

Comment: I say that look straight forward: you take a list of existing files, iterate over it and decide per conditional if a name with that file exists. If not, simple copy, otherwise copy and rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp source1/* target/
cp -f --backup --suffix='.copy' source2/* target/
```

Just note that this will not add `.copy` suffix to any files that are in `source2` but not in `source1`. That is, `.copy` will only be added for duplicate file names.

For multiple source folders, you can do something like:

```
cp source1/* target/
for i in {2..n} ; do
    cp -f --backup=numbered source${i}/* target/
done
```

Replace `n` with the your folder number. This will put a `.~1~` for the first copy, `.~2~` for the second copy and so on.

Comment: have 2 questions. this method is working.But I didn't mentioned that in the question but will update it now. what if I have multiple sources when I tried to copy files from another place, I also have to keep that file in the target folder. So what should I do in that case ? and I looked the cp's man page and didn't see the --suffix. where did you see "--suffix" ?

Comment: See my edited answer for multiple folders. The `--suffix` is also `-S` in the man page. I prefer the long option since it is clearer about what it does.

Comment: Thanks, @Munir that's working! I played little bit and this is also worked `cp -v --suffix='_'$i source${i}/* target/`

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Munir is perfect. My reputation is too low to comment on his solution, but I would like to mention on it why this works:

```
cp -f --backup --suffix='.copy' source2/* target/
```

Normally --backup will backup the file in the target folder, by appending a "~" at the end. The suffix option changes the "~" with copy. So why does this solution change the name of the source file and not the target? It's the addition of the -f option in the line, which is a radically different behavior than what -f normally does. This is documented in the last paragraph of the man page:

> As  a  special  case,  cp makes a backup of SOURCE when the force and backup options are given and SOURCE and DEST are the same name for an existing, regular file.

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to happen.